# How to determine first run of a javascript function?

Tags: javascript

I have a javascript function and I need to determine when the function run the very first time. How could I do that?

```
function myFunction(){
if (first_time){ //do something   }

else { ........... }

}
```

Comment: Does this run in a single context or does the page reload inbetween?

Comment: Just a note: You have accidentally comment out the closing bracket around the statements to be executed after the `if`-statement. You should also indent the `if`- and `else`-statements properly, since they are in a nested scope; it makes the code easier to read.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can create a pseudo static function property and check for its existence:

```
function myFunction(){
  if (!myFunction.didrun){ 
    //do something   
    myFunction.didrun = true;
  }
  else { ........... }
}
```

Comment: Lovely, doesn't rely on an external/global variable. I didn't know you could do this.

Comment: I like that your didrun boolean is sort of encapsulated

Comment: Yes, functions, like almost everything else in js, are instances of `Object`, that's why this is possible.

Comment: would `myFunction.didrun` `return false` first time this runs of do you need to check if it is `undefined`?

Comment: @Liam: no, if the property is not set it's `undefined` by default, so `if (!myFunction.didrun)` should be sufficient.

Comment: How it will work ? Always `myFunction.didrun`  will be `undefined`

Comment: @Vimalraj.S: no, only on first execution of the function. Within the if block, `myFunction.didrun` is set to `true`, so subsequent execution of `myFunction` will skip the block.

Comment: @KooiInc In the subsequent execution,let say in second execution `myFunction.didrun` is `undefined` . After the first execution completed `myFunction.didrun` will be destroyed.

Comment: I just saw your fiddle , In that instead of 
`myFunction();
myFunction();` , execute 
`myFunction();`
 and another 
`myFunction();`
 after 1 sec .you could find the problem

Comment: @Vimalraj.S you are wrong, sorry: http://jsbin.com/keposuje/3/
Do you even try things for yourself?

Comment: Glad I could help ;) @Vimalraj.S: it's ok. Use jsbin.com or jsfiddle more often to substantiate your statements, I'd advice.

Answer (score 1):

You can try with:

```
var first_time = true;

function myFunction(){

  if (first_time){
    first_time = false;
    // ...
  } else {
    // ...
  }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could set a global variable to true, once the function has been called.

```
var globalVar = false;

function myFunction(){
    globalVar = true;
    if (first_time){ //do something   }

    else { ........... }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Clearly very late to the party, I found these answers dissatisfying due to my personal performance requirements; the initial first-run conditional being wasteful (only in a hyper-optimized case, E.G. software raytracing).

I'm using the following:

```
function myFunction_theRest(){

   ...

}

function myFunction_first(){

   ...

   myFunction = myFunction_theRest;
}

var myFunction = myFunction_first;
```

Answer (score 0):

define a global var that will be incremented in each call of the function:

```
var nbCall= 0;
function myFunction(){
if (nbCall==0){ 
nbCall++;
 //do something   }

else { ........... }

}
```